# using history api with submit button

Tags: javascript, html, submit, single-page-application, browser-history

I am following along with this - http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html. In their example...they use this function:

```
function addClicker(link) {
   link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      swapPhoto(link.href);
      history.pushState(null, null, link.href);
      e.preventDefault();
   }, false);
}
```

I am wondering if I can pass the submit button as the `link` and do something like:

```
link.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      swapPhoto([submit button link]);
      history.pushState(null, null, [submit button link]);
      e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Basically, after a user logs in - a profile page template is loaded into my single-page-application. After log in, I want the user to be able to click the back button and go to the initial state of the index page.